Problem loading pretrained hugging face model on Kaggle
I was trying to load a bert pretrained model on Kaggle. The tokenizer of the model is loaded correctly, but the model doesn't want to start.
This is the model I want to train
class MyHyperModel(HyperModel):
    def build(self, hp):
        model = TFAutoModel.from_pretrained("gaunernst/bert-small-uncased", from_pt=True)

        input_ids = Input(shape=(512,), name='input_ids', dtype='int32')
        mask = Input(shape=(512,), name='attention_mask', dtype='int32')
        

        embeddings = model(input_ids, attention_mask=mask)[0]
        for i in range(hp.Int('num_bidir_rec_layers', 1, 3)):
          X = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=hp.Choice('LSTM_units', values=[64, 128])))(embeddings)
          X = Dropout(rate=hp.Choice('rate_dropout', values=[0.0, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7]))(X)
        for i in range(hp.Int('num_dense_layers', 0, 3)):
          X = Dense(units=hp.Choice('dense_units', values=[16, 32, 64, 128]), activation="relu")(X)
        y = Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax', name='outputs')(X)

        model = Model(inputs=[input_ids, mask], outputs=y)

        model.layers[2].trainable = False

        model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate = hp.Choice('learning_rate', values=[0.01, 1e-3]), clipnorm= hp.Choice('clip_norm', values= [1,3])), loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
        return model

This is the initialization of the GridSearch
tuner = GridSearch(
    hypermodel = MyHyperModel(),
    objective = Objective('val_loss', 'min'),
    max_trials = 10,
    seed = 42,
    executions_per_trial = 1,
    overwrite = True)

In this point it throws different exceptions varying the transformers package version.
In particular with 4.37.0 or 4.31.0, it throws:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[28], line 1
----> 1 tuner = GridSearch(
      2     hypermodel = MyHyperModel(),
      3     objective = Objective('val_loss', 'min'),
      4     max_trials = 10,
      5     seed = 42,
      6     executions_per_trial = 1,
      7     overwrite = True)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras_tuner/src/tuners/gridsearch.py:420, in GridSearch.__init__(self, hypermodel, objective, max_trials, seed, hyperparameters, tune_new_entries, allow_new_entries, max_retries_per_trial, max_consecutive_failed_trials, **kwargs)
    409 self.seed = seed
    410 oracle = GridSearchOracle(
    411     objective=objective,
    412     max_trials=max_trials,
   (...)
    418     max_consecutive_failed_trials=max_consecutive_failed_trials,
    419 )
--> 420 super().__init__(oracle, hypermodel, **kwargs)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/tuner.py:122, in Tuner.__init__(self, oracle, hypermodel, max_model_size, optimizer, loss, metrics, distribution_strategy, directory, project_name, logger, tuner_id, overwrite, executions_per_trial, **kwargs)
    114 if hypermodel is None and self.__class__.run_trial is Tuner.run_trial:
    115     raise ValueError(
    116         "Received `hypermodel=None`. We only allow not specifying "
    117         "`hypermodel` if the user defines the search space in "
    118         "`Tuner.run_trial()` by subclassing a `Tuner` class without "
    119         "using a `HyperModel` instance."
    120     )
--> 122 super().__init__(
    123     oracle=oracle,
    124     hypermodel=hypermodel,
    125     directory=directory,
    126     project_name=project_name,
    127     logger=logger,
    128     overwrite=overwrite,
    129     **kwargs,
    130 )
    132 self.max_model_size = max_model_size
    133 self.optimizer = optimizer

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/base_tuner.py:132, in BaseTuner.__init__(self, oracle, hypermodel, directory, project_name, overwrite, **kwargs)
    129     self.reload()
    130 else:
    131     # Only populate initial space if not reloading.
--> 132     self._populate_initial_space()
    134 # Run in distributed mode.
    135 if dist_utils.has_chief_oracle() and not dist_utils.is_chief_oracle():
    136     # Proxies requests to the chief oracle.
    137     # Avoid import at the top, to avoid inconsistent protobuf versions.

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/base_tuner.py:192, in BaseTuner._populate_initial_space(self)
    190 self.hypermodel.declare_hyperparameters(hp)
    191 self.oracle.update_space(hp)
--> 192 self._activate_all_conditions()

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/base_tuner.py:149, in BaseTuner._activate_all_conditions(self)
    147 hp = self.oracle.get_space()
    148 while True:
--> 149     self.hypermodel.build(hp)
    150     self.oracle.update_space(hp)
    152     # Update the recorded scopes.

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/hypermodel.py:120, in HyperModel._build_wrapper(self, hp, *args, **kwargs)
    116 if not self.tunable:
    117     # Copy `HyperParameters` object so that new entries are not added
    118     # to the search space.
    119     hp = hp.copy()
--> 120 return self._build(hp, *args, **kwargs)

Cell In[27], line 7, in MyHyperModel.build(self, hp)
      6 def build(self, hp):
----> 7     model = TFAutoModel.from_pretrained("gaunernst/bert-small-uncased", from_pt=True)
      9     input_ids = Input(shape=(512,), name='input_ids', dtype='int32')
     10     mask = Input(shape=(512,), name='attention_mask', dtype='int32')

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/auto/auto_factory.py:566, in _BaseAutoModelClass.from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, **kwargs)
    564 elif type(config) in cls._model_mapping.keys():
    565     model_class = _get_model_class(config, cls._model_mapping)
--> 566     return model_class.from_pretrained(
    567         pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, config=config, **hub_kwargs, **kwargs
    568     )
    569 raise ValueError(
    570     f"Unrecognized configuration class {config.__class__} for this kind of AutoModel: {cls.__name__}.\n"
    571     f"Model type should be one of {', '.join(c.__name__ for c in cls._model_mapping.keys())}."
    572 )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_utils.py:2902, in TFPreTrainedModel.from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, config, cache_dir, ignore_mismatched_sizes, force_download, local_files_only, token, revision, use_safetensors, *model_args, **kwargs)
   2899     model_kwargs["load_weight_prefix"] = load_weight_prefix + "/" + model_kwargs.get("name")
   2901 # Instantiate model.
-> 2902 model = cls(config, *model_args, **model_kwargs)
   2904 if tf_to_pt_weight_rename is None and hasattr(model, "tf_to_pt_weight_rename"):
   2905     # TODO Matt: This is a temporary workaround to allow weight renaming, but requires a method
   2906     #            to be defined for each class that requires a rename. We can probably just have a class-level
   2907     #            dict and a single top-level method or something and cut down a lot of boilerplate code
   2908     tf_to_pt_weight_rename = model.tf_to_pt_weight_rename

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/bert/modeling_tf_bert.py:1187, in TFBertModel.__init__(self, config, *inputs, **kwargs)
   1186 def __init__(self, config: BertConfig, *inputs, **kwargs):
-> 1187     super().__init__(config, *inputs, **kwargs)
   1189     self.bert = TFBertMainLayer(config, name="bert")

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_utils.py:1150, in TFPreTrainedModel.__init__(self, config, *inputs, **kwargs)
   1148 self.name_or_path = config.name_or_path
   1149 self.generation_config = GenerationConfig.from_model_config(config) if self.can_generate() else None
-> 1150 self._set_save_spec(self.input_signature)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/trackable/base.py:204, in no_automatic_dependency_tracking.<locals>._method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    202 self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    203 try:
--> 204   result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    205 finally:
    206   self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/layer.py:35, in TFLayer._set_save_spec(self, inputs, args, kwargs)
     33 kwargs_spec = {}
     34 # Filter out non-tensor arguments from kwargs.
---> 35 for key, kwarg in kwargs.items():
     36     flat_kwarg = tree.flatten(kwarg)
     37     flat_specs = [tf_utils.get_tensor_spec(x) for x in flat_kwarg]

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'


What should I fix to make it run properly? P.S. On colab works fine the same code and same transformers version, but I need way more GPU time!
